# Include a text file in a gh-pages jekyll template also available to js

Tags: github-pages

I'm making a "this day in history" sort of site in gh-pages, using javascript to pull the day's entry for the front page and a collection to store all the other entries indexed by date.

The entries are text files.

I've made markdown files as stubs to pull in the text files.  I don't want to replicate the text files if possible, because then any typos I would have to remember to fix in two places.

As far as I can see, there are two ways to include the text files in the template:

- {% include date.txt %} which requires the txt files to be in the _includes directory, thus not generated into the site and not available to the javascript on the front page
- {% include_relative date.txt %} which requires the txt file to be in the collection folder, which is also not generated unless it has a yaml header, in which case it would be difficult to extract the text from the generated html.

Is there another way I'm missing for jekyll to include plain text files without them having to be in special _folders?

I'm using github pages, so plugins are out.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way to include text files through liquid.  It is part of the way it separates published files from the pieces that go together to make the files.

The way forward is to adapt the javascript to read the text from a raw blob from the github repository.

But using an http request to raw.githubusercontent.com gives a Cross Origin Resource Sharing error.

So next way is to make a new collection with a new layout to output the input files as they are.